# Regex to match valid domain if it comes in beginning of a string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match the below criteria with Regex:

1. String starts with http or https
2. It ends with two particular domains (abc.com or xyz.com)
3. There can be anything after abc.com or xyz.com

I wrote below regex for the same:

```
http[s]?:\/\/(.*).(abc|xyz).com\/(.*)
```

but it fails in below scenario as it shouldn't be matched with the Regex.

```
http://www.attacker.com/https://events.abc.com/#/en/navigator/init/meetings
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Maybe just tell it to start searching at the beginning of the string: `^http[s]?:\/.....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

`^https?:\/\/([^\/]*\.)?(abc|xyz)\.com\/.*`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HgcFvL/4)

You have to check for characters except `/` before `abc|xyz.com`

**Details**

`^https?:\/\/`: `http://` or `https://` at the beginning of the string

`([^\/]*\.)?`: any character except  `/` before FQDN followed by dot, it's optional (`?`) for cases like `//abc.com`

`(abc|xyz)\.com`: match FQDN

`\/.*`: match `/` and anything that comes after

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the literals dots (`.`):
`https?:\/\/.*\.(abc|xyz)\.com\/.*`
See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/IQzAXt/1).

Of course, if you want to put that in a Java string literal, it's got to be
`https?:\\/\\/.*\\.(abc|xyz)\\.com\\/.*`

I also removed some unnecessary things from your regex:

1. You don't need to put single letters in a character class (`[s]`)
2. `(.*)` doesn't have to be in brackets, but it might be worth it to append a `?` to it, so it becomes `.*?` to avoid [greediness](https://blog.kiprosh.com/regular-expressions-greedy-vs-non-greedy/) of `*`

Comment: the regex is matched with the string mentioned in example. I need the regex which don't match

Comment: Yeah, but it's very confusing that your given example **does match** the criteria you are giving. It starts with `http`, ends with domain `abc.com` and then theres some stuff after that. Why should your example **not** match?